# GraphIQL Set URL Endpoint of Server

Tags: graphql, graphiql

I've spent the last hour or so looking through the GraphIQL guides and readme's.
I don't see any documentation about how to direct the client to a specific endpoint/port.
I am runni

I am running graphiql from the root of the project, locally. I have a graphql server running my backend and I just want to direct GraphIQL to it.

Comment: Have you considered `GraphQL Playground` as an alternative? https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-playground

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql/tree/main/packages/graphiql#options) outline all the props that are available on the `GraphiQL` React component. If you have a `GraphQLSchema` instance available, you can pass that directly in as the `schema` parameter. Otherwise, you just point your `fetcher` at the appropriate URL:

```
async function graphQLFetcher(graphQLParams) {
  return fetch(YOUR_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT_URL, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify(graphQLParams),
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .catch(() => response.text());
}

ReactDOM.render(<GraphiQL fetcher={graphQLFetcher} />, document.body);
```